# Can a non-calling Activity return result to the initial Activity via Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

The flow is like this:

A calls B (via `startActivityForResult`) which loads set of images. After a user pick one or more images, then B calls C where user can further sort images. After this step, C calls A calling `setResult(someResult, someIntent)`.

What happens in A is that I receive the correct request code, result code, but `null` intent.

Does A expect to get an `intent` from the class it called on the first place?

I thought it does and I passed this intent from B to C, but in C I had to dispose of that intent as B has to pass its own intent to A.

Comment: "After a user pick one or more images, then B calls C where user can further sort images" -- that's not really a supported flow. `startActivityForResult()` is for A invoking B, not B continuing on from there. "After this step, C calls A calling setResult(someResult, someIntent)" -- C is not calling A, as `setResult()` does not call an activity. I recommend that you get rid of C, moving its functionality into a fragment that B can pull up, so the entire choose-and-sort functionality is contained in one activity (B).

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought that this is a solution, but wanted to first check if I was making a mistake in passing the intent.

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly what `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` is for :-)

A should start B using `startActivityForResult()`. A's `onActivityResult()` will be called with the result.

B should start C using the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
intent.putExtra("...", ...); // If you need to pass additional data to C
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Note that B starts C using `startActivity()` instead of `startActivityForResult()`. However, because you specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`, C can now return a result to A (the Activity that originally started B).

In C, you should just call `setResult()` and `finish()` to return the result to A.

Comment: So all I missed was a flag? Wow I will check and mark this as the correct answer if it helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You should not call `A` from `C` but rather call `setResult()` in `C`, then `finish()` `C`, get the result in `B` then `finish()` `B` immediately (from `onActivityResult()`) and get the final result in `A` (in `onActivityResult()`).

The flow would be:

```
A: calls startActivityForResult(B)
  -> B: calls startActivityForResult(C)
    -> C: calls setResult() & finish()
  <- B: in onActivityResult(): calls setResult() & finish()
<- A: in onActivityResult(): get your result
```

Comment: Oh changing the flow with mutiple `startActivityForResult`! This idea may actually work

Comment: It works ;) And the UI is okay since `B` terminates immediately: the user won't see anything, `B` and `C` won't be in your flow history and the animations will be good.

Comment: I thought "may work" in my scenario. I know your advise works technically :) Thou not sure if it would be a good idea to use B as a jump step. I have to check this further...

Answer (score 2):

Well you can call onActivityResult twice to go to the activity A from the activity C, let me explain this further with a simple example...

In the A you Call b with activityforResult... if onResult comes with the proper result code then its returning from B after C then take the data and do something... 
Activity A:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{
    public static int A_REQUEST_CODE = 13215564;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, A_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == ActivityB.B_RESULT_CODE){
                //get the data an work on it
                data.getExtras().getString("CHANGE"); // Changed image
            }
    }
}
```

Then in B you call C with ActivityforResult after picking the image too, check if any result comes from C (will mean that will be returning from C) if thats the case then return to A and pass the intent

Activity B:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    public static int B_REQUEST_CODE = 64684687;
    public static int B_RESULT_CODE = 64004684;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = new Intent(this,ActivityC.class);
        Bundle info = new Bundle();
        info.putString("IMAGE", "IMAGE_PATH");
        startActivityForResult(i,B_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == B_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == ActivityC.C_RESULT_CODE){
            setResult(B_RESULT_CODE,data);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

In C just work the data and return to c with the proper result set

Activity C:

```
public class ActivityC extends Activity {

    public static int C_RESULT_CODE = 654846622;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String imageString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMAGE");
        //Work on the image then
        Intent i = new Intent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("CHANGE", "the changed image");
        i.putExtras(b);

        setResult(C_RESULT_CODE, i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

either change your architecture into fragments ... and handle this data passing in the host activity ,

or

do not `startActivityForResult`  simply use `startActivity` and surf through activities, and when the images has been sorted or whatever in the C activity, just again `startActivity(A)` with your data as Extra in the intent, now back to activity A, in the onCreate Method, check for the `getIntent` and `hasExtra` methods, if it has, means you are sending back the data, and so do whatever you wanna do on the `onResult`,

again the fragment method is way better, of course

EDIT:
just saw @shkschneider's answer, that seems legit if you insist on using activities

Comment: I don't think the `startActivityForResult()` is a bad option. Calling again `A` with extra is not a good flow IMHO because the animation will make believe it's a new launch and it could be stored in history etc etc.

Comment: I agree with you, I still think using fragments is the better approach here, but you answer works best if using activities is a must !

Comment: I have to use Activities in this scenario. I also need a result. Your approach could work but then I don't have the result. And checking for null intent or extra is never a good idea (in case the real null returns)